# Proxy sub domains without redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, proxy, subdomain

Need to redirect requests sent to, for instance, sub domain auto.domain.int to www.domain.int/doc/sample-rates. It is a Zend application so MVC is used. I have the following in my .htaccess conf:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^auto\.domain\.int$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /doc/sample-rates [PT,L]
```

The thing is, when I put a name of a real file on filesystem as the RewriteRule substitution, lets say 'script.php', it all works well. The content of the script.php file served under the auto.domain.int hostname.

On the other hand when I put an MVC route as the RewriteRule substitution I got 500 error from apache for '/doc/sample-rates' path and 400 error for 'http://www.domain.int/doc/sample-rates' path and several lines in apache log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d75058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/ -> 
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d75058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri ''
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d75058/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] rewrite '' -> '/doc/sample-rates'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d75058/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] forcing '/doc/sample-rates' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d75058/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] internal redirect with /doc/sample-rates [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d67018/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] add path info postfix: /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/doc -> /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/doc/sample-rates
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d67018/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/doc/sample-rates -> doc/sample-rates
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d67018/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'doc/sample-rates'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d67018/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] rewrite 'doc/sample-rates' -> '/doc/sample-rates'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d67018/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] forcing '/doc/sample-rates' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2013:10:50:19 --0500] [auto.domain.int/sid#b73cd9d8][rid#b6d67018/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/domain/base/www.domain.com/htdocs/] internal redirect with /doc/sample-rates [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Updated: auto.domain.int is an alias for the "main" www.domain.int using ServerAlias.

Thanks,
Eugene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add an additional `RewriteCond` to prevent an endless rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^auto\.domain\.int$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/doc/sample-rates$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /doc/sample-rates [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Olaf, but the first one doesn't help a lot and the second is redirect which I do not want to use.

Comment: @ladjack What does "doesn't help a lot" mean? Is the behaviour exactly the same? Has anything changed?

Comment: Well yes, keep getting the "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" error messages...

Comment: @ladjack This works fine in my test environment. There might be some other rule causing this redirects. Is `/doc/sample-rates` a real file or directory? Or is there some rule or alias forwarding to yet another location?