# Avoid 400 from Apache for RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

### Situation

**For development** I want to use an Apache VHost for delivering frontend files from my machine, but API calls (via JS `fetch`: POST, PUT, DELETE) being redirected to a server far from home.

#### VHost

Config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test-co2avatar.localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/myname/work/sdp/test-frontends
    Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

    # https://content-security-policy.com/style-src/
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-co2avatar\.localhost$
    RewriteRule co2avatar-app/sdp-api$ https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api [L,PT]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-co2avatar\.localhost$
    RewriteRule co2avatar-app/sdp-api/(.*)$ https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/$1 [L,PT]

    # for avoiding 403 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38353249/2092322
    <Directory "/home/myname/work/sdp/test-frontends">
        Require all granted

        RewriteEngine On

        # now: https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/react-router-in-the-real/content/apache.html
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        RewriteRule co2avatar-app/(.*)/(js|style|resources)/(.+)\.(.+)$ co2avatar-app/$2/$3.$4 [END]
            
        # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-co2avatar\.localhost$
        # RewriteRule co2avatar-app/sdp-api$ https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api [L,PT]
        
        # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-co2avatar\.localhost$
        # RewriteRule co2avatar-app/sdp-api/(.*)$ https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/$1 [L,PT]

        # anything else to index.html
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-co2avatar\.localhost$
        RewriteRule co2avatar-app/(.+) co2avatar-app/index.html [L]
    </Directory>

    # LogLevel debug

    # SSL
    # self signed cert for development
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/share/apache2/cert/co2compass-local.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/share/apache2/cert/co2compass-local.key"

</VirtualHost>
```

#### Result

##### Frontend files

Are delivered very fine (JS, CSS, image, fonts etc.)

##### Rewrite to server for getting data traffic done fails

From Apache error.log

```
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.654207 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 46526:tid 140357610219264] [client ::1:34698] AH01964: Connection to child 9 established (server co2avatar.localhost:443)
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.654375 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 46526:tid 140357610219264] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2372): [client ::1:34698] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername test-co2avatar.localhost found
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.654390 2021] [core:debug] [pid 46526:tid 140357610219264] protocol.c(2313): [client ::1:34698] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server test-co2avatar.localhost
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.657156 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 46526:tid 140357610219264] [client ::1:34698] AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server co2avatar.localhost:443)
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.657197 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 46526:tid 140357610219264] SSL Library Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown (SSL alert number 46)
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.657207 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 46526:tid 140357610219264] [client ::1:34698] AH01998: Connection closed to child 9 with abortive shutdown (server test-co2avatar.localhost:443)
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.662640 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] [client ::1:34700] AH01964: Connection to child 67 established (server co2avatar.localhost:443)
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.663077 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2372): [client ::1:34700] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername test-co2avatar.localhost found
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.663114 2021] [core:debug] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] protocol.c(2313): [client ::1:34700] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server test-co2avatar.localhost
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.664964 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2254): [client ::1:34700] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.3, Cipher: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665204 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] ssl_engine_kernel.c(415): [client ::1:34700] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 67 (server test-co2avatar.localhost:443), referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665247 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:34700] ::1 - - [test-co2avatar.localhost/sid#7fa796c635f0][rid#7fa79778b0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login, referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665254 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:34700] ::1 - - [test-co2avatar.localhost/sid#7fa796c635f0][rid#7fa79778b0a0/initial] applying pattern 'co2avatar-app/sdp-api$' to uri '/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login', referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665267 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:34700] ::1 - - [test-co2avatar.localhost/sid#7fa796c635f0][rid#7fa79778b0a0/initial] applying pattern 'co2avatar-app/sdp-api/(.*)$' to uri '/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login', referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665278 2021] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:34700] ::1 - - [test-co2avatar.localhost/sid#7fa796c635f0][rid#7fa79778b0a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='test-co2avatar.localhost' pattern='^test-co2avatar\\.localhost$' => matched, referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665283 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:34700] ::1 - - [test-co2avatar.localhost/sid#7fa796c635f0][rid#7fa79778b0a0/initial] rewrite '/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login' -> 'https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login', referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665299 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:34700] ::1 - - [test-co2avatar.localhost/sid#7fa796c635f0][rid#7fa79778b0a0/initial] implicitly forcing redirect (rc=302) with https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login, referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665304 2021] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client ::1:34700] ::1 - - [test-co2avatar.localhost/sid#7fa796c635f0][rid#7fa79778b0a0/initial] forcing '{PROT}test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler, referer: https://test-co2avatar.localhost/co2avatar-app/input/ghg-domain/housing/values
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665546 2021] [headers:debug] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] mod_headers.c(899): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
[Wed Sep 01 16:34:10.665652 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 46527:tid 140357728802560] ssl_engine_io.c(1102): [client ::1:34700] AH02001: Connection closed to child 67 with standard shutdown (server test-co2avatar.localhost:443)
```

#### Problem

##### SSL

I don't quite understand the error: `SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown (SSL alert number 46)`.

But I thing the second *shutdown* is more important here:

##### Loop?

The error **forcing '{PROT}test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api/login' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler** seems to say that there is and endless redirect/rewrite going on.

But I have no idea anymore.

#### Solutions

[Adding a `RewriteCond`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206826/2092322) for my local VHost did not work. I've also tried to move the `RewriteRule` outside of the `<Directory>` stuff, but this did not change anything

Do I need to use a proxy here instead? How else can I rewrite calls to another server/domain?

Comment: For reverse proxying a request to a different host, you need [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html).

Comment: @DanielW. So it is not possible to use the `P` flag: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p: *For example, if you wanted all image requests to be handled by a back-end image server*

Comment: Oh you are probably right, `P` flag is sufficient. I'm more into nginx >.< What makes me think it doesn't work is the 302 redirect, it shouldn't send one, should it? `implicitly forcing redirect (rc=302)`

Comment: @DanielW. Using `proxy_module` was indeed more easy in my case. I was not able to finish rewriting for a redirect for the certain path `sdp-api`. Using a different domain / server seems to be different than just changing the path. Or the SSL error was the actual problem. Anyway, not it works, thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution uses `proxy_module` instead of rewrites.

```
# because we use https for localhost, too
SSLProxyEngine on
# SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/co2avatar-app/sdp-api" "https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api"
ProxyPassReverse "/co2avatar-app/sdp-api" "https://test.co2avatar.org/co2avatar-app/sdp-api"
```

There are options for using the more flexible [*rewrite* module, for example with `RedirectMatch` or just `[P]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs).

But there are quite a few rewrite rules in my configuration and I was not able to get it work (order, conditions, (end) flags). So I am using the simple proxy / reverse proxy pattern.